# Is paging broken in Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a folder with 18 files. If I do a list with maxResults=20, I get all 18. So far so good.

If I set maxResults=10, I get 10 and a...

```
 "nextPageToken": "!!|~EAIaggELEgA6egpi96NuFMj_____f_8AAP__AAD_KFSjepDGzcnNxs3GzMnPy8jRyNGqpsyrlMusoLmnlP8AAP__AP7__n__AP8AKFSjepDGzcnNxs3GzMnPy8jRyNGqpsyrlMusoLmnlP8A__4QESF03OHBi8LW0zkAAAAAN-uRXEgBDEAAIgsJb4Vcq9cAAAAgBg"
```

... so far so good.

If I then request another 10 using the pageToken

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?pageToken=!!%7C~EAIaggELEgA6egpi96NuFMj_____f_8AAP__AAD_KFSjepDGzcnNxs3GzMnPy8jRyNGqpsyrlMusoLmnlP8AAP__AP7__n__AP8AKFSjepDGzcnNxs3GzMnPy8jRyNGqpsyrlMusoLmnlP8A__4QESF03OHBi8LW0zkAAAAAN-uRXEgBDEAAIgsJb4Vcq9cAAAAgBg&maxResults=10&q='0Bw3h_yCVtXbbQ1BzcU5TbXl1T1k'+in+parents+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=nextLink%2CnextPageToken%2Citems(description%2Cid%2Ctitle)%2CnextPageToken
```

... I get 1 item, and no nextPageToken, instead of the expected 8.

If I do the same thing from the API Explorer, I get 10 and 8 as expected. The difference is that the API Explorer gives a much shorter nextPageToken. I also noticed that the API Explorer gives status 200 for both GETs. My app is sometimes given 304, but isn't consistent. I suspect the significant difference is that my app has drive.file scope. This shouldn't be a problem, remember that if I request 20 I get all 18 files.

Some more testing, if I set ...

- maxResults=4, I get 15 files.
- maxResults=6 or 7 gives me 18 (woot!!).
- maxResults=11 gives me 14
- maxResults=12 gives me 14
- maxResults=16 gives me (you won't believe this one ...) 24!. Yes 24 even though the folder only has 18 files. I've checked the returned file IDs and 6 of them are duplicated.

A public bug list would be very helpful right now!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is yes [files.list() reproducibly returns incomplete list in "drive.files" scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186264/files-list-reproducibly-returns-incomplete-list-in-drive-files-scope). This bug has been outstanding since April