# What is the expected behaviour of the changes feed with drive.file scope?

Tags: google-drive-api

My expectation is that if I query the Changes Feed with a scope of drive.file, I will only receive changes to files owned by my application.

However, in testing that I have done, I am seeing files in the feed that have nothing to do with my app. At least some of them are files that have been shared with me.

Anybody know exactly how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 0**

Similar or duplicate StackOverflow questions

- [Listing files with search query returns out-of-scope results (drive.files.list call, using drive.files scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821979/listing-files-with-search-query-returns-out-of-scope-results-drive-files-list-c)
- [List ignores drive.file scope and shows shared files not created by the calling app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301434/list-ignores-drive-file-scope-and-shows-shared-files-not-created-by-the-calling)

---

The files returned will not be specific to your app. Files that are "public on the web" are also reported back, regardless of whether or not your app created them or they were ever opened by the user in your app.

There is a parameter (`includeSubscribed`) that will filter out shared docs but this is also a bit limited (see below).

From [Detect Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes):

> For Google Drive apps that need to keep track of changes to files,
>   polling repeatedly can be both inefficient and resource-intensive. The
>   Changes feed provides a more efficient way to detect changes to **all
>   files, including those that have been shared with a user.** The feed
>   works by providing the current state of each file, if and only if the
>   file has changed since the given changestamp.

Here is a relevant parameter from [Changes:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list).

> **includeSubscribed** *boolean*
>
> Whether to include shared files and public
>   files the user has opened. When set to false, the list will include
>   owned files plus any shared or public files the user has explictly
>   added to a folder in Drive. (Default: true)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already aware of the published, "standard" changes feed behaviour. My question is specifically how this behaviour is altered when the app is using drive.file scope. Are specifically saying that the "all files" that you have marked in bold will override the fact that my app only has permissions to see its own files via its drive.file scope?

Comment: I'd say based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes#google_drive_scopes), you should only see "per-file access to files created or opened by the app" if you selected drive.file for the scope.

Comment: That's what I'd expect too. Which is why I don't understand why I'm getting various other files, most of which were created years before the app in question.

Comment: [The wording here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list#auth) makes me think it's just used for authentication and not for filtering out what is visible (that, of course, doesn't make sense to me). Have you tried other scopes to see if there is a difference (drive.metadata.readonly or drive.appdata for example).

Comment: With other scopes I get all changed files, which is what I expect. drive.file is the preferred scope for third-party apps because it gives the user the comfort that the app cannot access files that the app didn't initially create. And it seems to do just that, except when applied to the changes feed.

Comment: [Here's a similar issue that was supposedly fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821979/listing-files-with-search-query-returns-out-of-scope-results-drive-files-list-c). I think this appears to be a bug. [Also, see if this solution works.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18301786/1085891)

Comment: smells like a bug to me too. I checked the link you suggested, but it's talking about cookies which is orthogonal to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Scope**(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file)
**Meaning**(Per-file access to files created or **opened by the app**)

The scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file strikes this balance in a practical way. Presumably, **users only open or create a file with an app that they trust**, for reasons they understand.

But though, to your point, please refer to this [q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301434/list-ignores-drive-file-scope-and-shows-shared-files-not-created-by-the-calling).

Comment: Did you read the other answers & comments on this question? All this has been discussed already.