# sharedWithMe does not work with drive.file scope

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on a .NET Google Drive app with scope drive.file. My app does not show up the list of shared files through the query Q = sharedWithMe. However, when I change my app's scope to drive the list of files appears. Why does it not work when the scope is set to drive.file? I created another project on Drive console and tested it but again it failed.

Comment: did you ever found a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Drive.Files scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes) states it only gives access to files opened or created by the app.   The new API is more restrictive of file scope, I believe because Google is trying to push dev's to use the new [google file picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) (as a security measure), to get access to files not created by the app.

Your solutions are:

1. use the Google file picker.
2. use the previous api, and use a broader scope.
3. share explicity with app (@pinoyyid answer), e.g. by creating an [application owned account](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts).

**Update:** I just tested, and can confirm your results.  "Created by application" is not an attribute shared between accounts.  It only affects the original account.

Comment: No, I don't want to use files outside of the Drive.Files scope. I am sharing the files using my app which has scope Drive.File. When I am logged in to my app as the other user (which is in the shared list of people) the list of shared files is empty, while in Drive API the files are present.

Comment: Can you please explain me this: ""Created by application" is not an attribute shared between accounts. It only affects the original account." Thank you

Comment: When you create a document with an app, the user's Google account flags your app has having privileges on that file.  But it is specific to that account.  If you share the document, and someone else has a copy of your app on their account, your app has no special privilege to open that document.

Comment: Aham, got it. The three alternatives you gave me are not suitable for my domain: 1. I need to list files not to pick them 2. I must use a restrictive scope 3. files must be distributed among users. Is there a way to explicitly tell to Google Drive (in the drive.file scope) that the file created with my app and shared with others can also be opened by them?

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of any other ways.

Answer (score 1):

**drive.file** can only see files that were created with the app, or explicitly shared with the app. Sharing a file with the user is not enough, it needs to be shared with the app also.

Answer (score 1):

with Drive.File scope, each individual user needs to authorize your app to see the file.

Thus, if you share the file, the user its shared with needs to explicitly open the file with your app in order for you to view it in that context.

Comment: I am using the same app for creating, sharing and opening the files. The scenario is like this: a user uploads a file through my app and shares it with another user, which in turn through my app (q=sharedWithMe) should see the file. The last user cannot see this file. So, the user cannot explicitly open the file to view it. The user has given authorization to my app with drive.file scope. Why he cannot see the file?

Comment: "Why he cannot see the file? "  See my answer above as well as Cheryl's! User B must shared the file with your app. Only then can the app running under User B's account see the file.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, drive.file scope permissions seem inconsistent.

For example (all actions are performed by the app with drive.file scope):

- userA creates a folderA (using **files.insert**)
- userA creates a file inside folderA called fileA (using **/upload/drive/v2/files**)
- userA shares folderA and fileA with userB (using **permissions.insert**)
- userB can see information about both folderA and fileA (using **files.get**) (*So app on UserB account has access to both the folder and the file*)
- if userA runs children.list on folderA or **files.list with q:folderA in parents**, it will show fileA
- if userB runs the same command it will not show fileA

I apologize for complexity of the above example, I can setup a simple javascript demo if that would be helpful.

I could not find anywhere in Google Drive documentation that claims any restrictions about accessing application created files on different accounts, so it might be a bug introduced trying to solve scope violation bugs last year.

For example:
[List ignores drive.file scope and shows shared files not created by the calling app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301434/list-ignores-drive-file-scope-and-shows-shared-files-not-created-by-the-calling)