# drive.file scope and template files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I want to make my application use a limited scope in Google Drive, namely **drive.file**.

With this scope if I want to create a new file in the drive, by copying an existing file from another user, which has the permission 'anyone with the link' as read, the copy fails.

This has already been asked [a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344045/sharedwithme-does-not-work-with-drive-file-scope), but the possibilities seems to have narrowed since, as the suggestion of an application owned account seems now deprecated : all links on application owned accounts are broken.

**Question:** Is there a means of having an application using the limited scope drive.file, while still creating its files by copying them from a file shared for reading, using some sort of service account ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding read-write access to file metadata by [authorizing with the following scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing):

- **`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata`**
- **`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly`**

This related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33335396) suggests the same.

Comment: The drive.metadata or drive.metadata.readonly do not help: used with drive.file it doesn't give access to files shared with the user.


After some trial I found that drive.readonly + drive.metadata works, with a caveat : we still have a Google security popup triggered by the use of drive.readonly. 


This is apparently because drive.readonly is still too much privilege for a non reviewed Google Drive app (we just need to read only one shared template file, outside of the user drive).