# Listing files with Google Drive API returns out-of-scope results (again)

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm an Android developer, using the Google Drive API for month now.

I got a rise in customer complaints recently (the app is live): my app is only using the drive.file and the drive.appdata scopes, but I noticed that search queries are now returning files not created (nor shared!) by my app! Almost thousands of results.

This can be [easily verified using the API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/drive/v2/drive.files.list?q=mimeType%20%253D%20%27application%252Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27) by only checking the "drive.file" scope with an empty query string (or a folder query only).

The same thing happens using the change API: I'm now getting a change for every file recently viewed by the owner!

This is clearly an out-of-scope bug! There was a similar bug last year, but it seems the problem is back:

[Listing files with search query returns out-of-scope results (drive.files.list call, using drive.files scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821979/listing-files-with-search-query-returns-out-of-scope-results-drive-files-list-c)

My app is clearly broken, and that's a *big* privacy concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've isolated a Google Drive server issue and have implemented a temporary fix. You should no longer be able to see the issue.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Will look at it. Thanks for prompt reply !